# Schedule auto-startup and auto-shutdown of AWS EC2 instances without using AWS Lambda [not available in AWS GovCloud]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, startup, shutdown

Is there an existing implementation service / workflow provided by AWS that supports scheduling auto-shutdowns and auto-startups?

I'm surprising it's just not baked directly into the EC2 instance. I can't use AWS Instance Scheduler (and AWS Lambda) because AWS Lambda is not available in AWS GovCloud.

Comment: Lambda has been available in GovCloud (US-West) since May 2017.

Comment: You should post this question on serverfault.com. Stackoverflow is for questions about programming; serverfault is for questions about professional server software and administration.